# Add values from a column when two other columns match

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have an ecology data table with about 12,000 rows.  There are three columns: `site`, `species`, and `value`.  I need to add up the values for each set of matching site and species - for example, all "red maple" values at "site A".  I have the data sorted by `site` and `species`, so I can do it by hand, but it's slow going.  The number of `site`/`species` matches varies, so I can't just add up the values in sets of three or anything.

Similar types of questions have talked about pivot tables, but none have needed to match two columns and add a third column, and I haven't been able to figure out how to extrapolate to my situation.

I'm reasonably comfortable coding and would like to do something that looks like this pseudocode, but I'm not clear on the syntax in VBA:

```
For each row
if a(x) = a(x+1) and b(x) = b(x+1) then
sum = sum + c(x)
else
d(x) = sum
sum = 0
next
```

Any ideas?

Comment: pivot table is the way to go, just learn how to properly use it

Answer (score 2):

In a PivotTable, put `site` in Row Labels and `species` in Column Labels (or vice versa) and Sum of  `value` in Σ Values:

[image: SO19274376 example]